# How to add a progress bar

Tags: javascript, ng-file-upload

I just started using `ng-file-upload` and it was a little complicated at the beginning but after some time reading I could achieve some things. But now Im stuck trying to add a progress bar, Im uploading pictures into Firebase and it works well, I can save it, update it and show the picture on the view, now I just need to add a progress bar to know what's going on while it's uploading.

I know the info to do it and some samples are out there but I can't find out how to add it to my code, hope you can give me a hand.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
$scope.submit = function(file) {

        Auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
        $scope.authData = authData;

            if(authData){
                if ($scope.file) {

                    console.log($scope.file);

                    var refImg = new Firebase("http://url.firebaseio.com/users/" + authData.uid);

                    Upload.base64DataUrl($scope.file).then(function(base64Urls) {
                        refImg.update({
                        FotoPerfil : base64Urls
                        });
                    });
                }    
            }
            else{
                window.location.href = '#/Bienvenidos';
            }
        });
    };
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="btn btn-default" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" ngf-min-height="100">Select picture profile</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>  

<img src="{{perfil.FotoPerfil}}" ngf-no-object-url="true" />
```

Thanks so much,

Daniel

Comment: You are uploading the base64 data url of the file using Firebase. So you gotta look if Firebase provide any functionality to be able to listen to the progress event. If it doesn't then the alternative would be to use Upload.http() instead.

Answer (score 2):

How about using firebase storage with firebase 3.0?